# rusty stains showing through a newly dried spackle

Tags: drywall, mold, moisture, patching-drywall

I noticed the wall by my balcony door was soft and sticking out, figured somehow there was moisture and possibly mold growing underneath the drywall lining. So I ripped that part out, scraped a little, cleaned with bleach and let dry. Then applied a thin first layer of spackle compound.

After it dried, there are a few reddish, rusty looking spots shining through. There are no nails anywhere around.

Anyone knows whats going on here? Why did the inside of the drywall get moist in the first place and what are the spots?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a leak - that's what causes moist drywall in virtually all cases. The rust is presumably coming from drywall nails/screws or other nails or steel/iron in the wall. Without fixing the leak first, no repair will last. Once you get the leak fixed you can coat the wall with a "stain-blocking primer" (often shellac based) to stop the rust stains from bleeding through the paint.